# Unity Mail handling multiple accounts

Tags: unity, 12.10, notification, mail

I've configured Unity Mail so it monitors 2 email accounts (say, Gmail and Mail.ru). It correctly notifies me about new messages, but when I click on an unread message it either redirects me to Gmail or does nothing in the case of Mail.ru.

Is there a possibility of configuring Unity Mail so it can handle different redirect pages with the respect to email accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click on an unread message in the Messaging Menu, it shouldn't open anything unless you set up an "Inbox[]" URL. To set it up, do the following:

- open the configuration file (`~/.config/unity-mail.conf`) in any editor;
- if there is no `[URLs]` section, add it (simply append this line to the file);
- in `[URLs]` section, add lines like these:

  ```
  Inbox[yourname@gmail.com] = http://mail.google.com/mail/
  Inbox[yourname@mail.ru] = http://mail.ru/...
  ```

  (of course you can use any emails/URLs there). Now it should open the specified URL when you click on the unread message.

Comment: I had to restart Unity Mail for this to work