# multiple gmail account notifier ubuntu 13.04

Tags: notification, notify-osd, gmail

in 12.04 i used an app that used NotifyOSD to notify me if i got one of my three gmail accounts.
and sadly i cant find it for 13.04.
Both gm-notify and gm-notifier only works with 1 gmail acount.

Is there any notifier app that works with multiple gmail accounts and uses notofyOSD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found popper throught GetDEb and it works just the way i want it: http://www.getdeb.net/updates/Ubuntu/13.04/?q=popper

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work in 14.10 or I'm doing smth wrong

Answer (score 3):

### [Unity Mail](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/unity-mail) [image: Install unity-mail]

With Unity Mail we can handle multiple gmail accounts. You will get an OSD notification whenever you receive a new mail showing the sender, and the subject of a mail.

[image]

In addition it adds a launcher icon to display the count of unread messages, integrates with the mail indicator to turn it blue, and displays a list of mails in the drop down menu there.

[image]

[image: Install via the software center]

For newer releases (>= 15.10) Unity-Mail can be installed from the official ppa:

**ppa:robert-tari/main**

Comment: I tried this, but multiple account handling isnt so great... it always opened my first mail's page, so I'm sticking with popper, thanks anyway!

Comment: Takkat, you're using Ubuntu 13.04, right? I see you don't have those status icons (Available, Away, Busy...) in the Messaging Menu? How did you get rid of them? Thanks. :)

Comment: @user74660: sorry to say - I made the screenshots from a VM which got deleted later. No chance to find out what I did there. Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu

Comment: No problem, Takkat. I appreciate your attention, anyway. Thanks. :)

Comment: @NaGeL182 for Unity Mail to open corresponding account page you may use this answer http://askubuntu.com/a/227047/284664, link format for different gmail accounts is following: https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#inbox (change number after 'u' for different accounts)